# Application that allows access to the other os in a multi-boot computer

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, multi-boot

Is there any application that allows  access to the other os in a multi-boot computer?
Access like in a virtual machine. Wherein you are able to see your other installation through it. Make file modifications, installs, and uninstalls. And those changes are being mirrored in your physical os when you boot to it?

Comment: There are applications to allow you to make file modifications (basically allow you to access the other OS's partition) but as to accessing as in "booting" it up as if it was running native to change it... I'm not sure.

Comment: what's the name of the app you are talking about?

Comment: Well, basically they let you explore the OS's partition as if it were another hard drive... I'm not sure if they are what you are thinking about. But if they are, it depends on operating system. MacDrive is one for Windows and OS X, there's ext2/3 drivers online to download  (I haven't found any satisfactory ones though) for accessing linux partitions from windows explorer. I'm not an expert, so better wait for an answer. :)

Comment: Yep, there's an answer now, and I agree with Ignacio :). If you only want to modify files though as if another hard drive that is quite a bit easier and safer (previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

The success of trying to boot a "native" OS in a VM depends on a number of factors.

The first is the operating system that you're trying to use as a guest. Most versions of Windows are *very* hostile to hardware changing underneath them, whereas most versions of Linux don't care as long as the appropriate drivers are available when the guest is started.

The second is the bootloader you use to start the OS. Some allow for the flexibility of being called from any disk location, physical or otherwise. Others complain over any little change. If you install a second bootloader to handle differences in the configurations then you now become responsible for keeping them synchronized should any changes to either be done.

In short, you're best off not trying this.